# Why use numpy.array() on numpy.arange()? Isn't it redundant?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

In my Numpy / Pandas lesson I am taught to make data with the following code:

```
sample_numpy_data = np.array(np.arange(24)).reshape((6,4))
```

Isn't it redundant to use np.array() on the np.arange() as np.arange() already produces an array?

Why is this necessary? example?

*Example found in Lynda course "Pandas for Data Science" Pandas Overview -
 Operations.*

Comment: Yup.  That is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not only redundant, it also introduces unnecessary overhead because it [makes a copy of the array by default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array).

If you're not sure if something is an array (maybe because it's an argument for a function) you can use `np.asarray` on it. That only copies if it's not an array.